# default text in textarea for insert into

Tags: php

How do I add default text for new textarea without affecting the view mode?

```
<textarea name='reason' cols='40' rows='12' wrap='virtual' style='width:96%'
 ><?php echo $viewmode ? text($result['reason']) : text($GLOBALS['default_chief_complaint']); ?></textarea>
```

This code is from OpenEMR's encounter form. Is it possible to set a template for new encounter form for it to be inserted to table then when in view mode the template won't show up?

I have already tried this:

```
<textarea name='reason' cols='40' rows='12' wrap='virtual' style='width:96%'
 >Consult by: <?php echo $viewmode ? text($result['reason']) : text($GLOBALS['default_chief_complaint']); ?></textarea>
```

It does submit but in view mode it shows

```
 Consult by: Consult by: test
```

I need this to be inside textarea coz I'm trying to standardize the encounter format

Comment: so you basically want to store at DB but don't want to show in view, right?

Comment: Why not put "Consult by" outside of the text area? `<div>Consult by: <textarea ....><?php ....?></textarea></div>`

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon yup sorry if my question was too confusing

Comment: @kojow7 coz i want it to be inside, there will be more stuffs inside the template.. consult by, procedure done by etc..

Comment: Then I am wondering why you are not creating separate form fields for each of these? It would be much more easier to process on the backend if each was separated.

Comment: @kojow7 if i understand you correctly, do you mean to create separate columns each for consult by, procedure done by? i think this might be feasible. let me try and get back to you. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: there is no such option to put default value in `<textarea/>` field like `<input default=""/>` field. What you can do, you can show/hide the entire `<textarea/>` field based on condition.

Comment: @hj_chua Maybe, what I mean is that `consult by` should have its own textarea (or input), `procedure done by` should have its own textarea (or input), etc.

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon The default value for a textarea is the content. I.e. what's between the opening and closing <textarea> tags.

Comment: then why not try this - `<textarea name="hide" style="display:none;">your default value</textarea>`

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon okay let me explain it this way>> the textarea uses a template and record the initial patient encounter. once the patient has done procedures, the textarea will be used to edit the template to add names and type of procedures done

Comment: I am not familiar with OpenEMR, but if you want to have a look of a text area, you can create a div with a white background. Add a border around it and it will look like a text area. Then for each of the fields inside the div you can use inputs (for single line entries) and textareas for multiple line entries). You can remove the border and outline from those inputs so that they do not show up. Labels such as "consult by" should be labels and not part of the text inside the input or textareas.

Comment: @kojow7 thanks bro. saved a lot time making it simple that way